# How to create a Magento 2 Patch?

Tags: magento2, module, patches

I am working on a Magento module that requires a quick fix.
I assume I can fix it by creating Magento 2 "patch" way.

I have never created a patch file before, can anyone help me to create a patch file for a custom module?

Comment: Hey can you please tell me that how to create a patch for composer.json?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I use this method for creating patch, hope it helps .
Let suppose you will modify this file

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php

Create a copy of that file with your changes on it:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerDataModified.php

What you need to do is run this command:

```
diff -u CustomerData.php CustomerDataModified.php > diff.patch
```

Move **diff.patch** in your root under a directory, example **Mypatches** dir .
Delete the file added CustomerDataModified.php since the patch is generated with the changes.

Here comes the tricky part , needs some manual modification now :
When you open the diff.patch you will get something like this on the top :

```
--- CustomerData.php    2018-02-21 01:26:16.000000000 -0500
+++ CustomerDataModified.php    2019-01-03 03:57:47.326011737 -0500
```

Replace those line with this one:

```
diff --git a/Block/CustomerData.php b/Block/CustomerData.php
index 3ee2rd..8349152 111644
--- a/Block/CustomerData.php
+++ b/Block/CustomerData.php
```

The index is needed (the numbers are generated by me random, by default are generated from git but in most cases the vendor is in **.gitignore**)

Next Step is modification of the **composer.json** in the root of your magento :
Add the extra section (if you dont have one already)

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-customer": {
                "some description abt issue applying this patch": "Mypatches/diff.patch"
            }
        }
    }
```

And there you go . Your patch is **diff.patch** (you can call whatever you like ) .
Run `composer install` to apply that

Comment: Let me know if it works for you .

Comment: This works exactly what I am looking for. Thanks dude.

Comment: Glad it helped :).

Comment: Easily Understanable @YlgenGuxholli, All type of patches generated using this formula ?

Comment: Works as expected. Many thanks, Ylgen!

Comment: I just tried this and I didn't need to add the lines starting with diff and index, just changed CustomerDataModified to CustomerData in the second line and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a n00b with these patches, so I'm not well versed in this. What does the a/ and b/ represent? Is this meant to be replaced with the relative path? If so, why a/ and b/?

Comment: I keep coming back to this comment for several changes, great explanation! Small note that the `index 3ee2rd..8349152 111644` line is not necessary. I left it out and the patch applies perfectly fine. At least, this is on Magento 2.4.6 with Composer 2.5.5

Answer (score 45):

Here is my answer, i hope it will help someone:

First make sure that this package is installed via composer: `cweagans/composer-patches`

Lets say you want to apply a patch from a third-party module installed via composer for a controller. Please make sure that you have this part in the composer.json file:

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": true,
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patches": {
        "vendorname/module-somerandomname": {
            "Description here": "patches/my_patch_name.patch"
        }
    }
},
```

Assuming that your vendor folder is in the .gitignore file, you can still do:

1. `git add -f vendor/vendorname/module-somerandomname/Controller/Myfile.php`
2. Do your changes to the Myfile.php
3. Do a `git diff vendor/vendorname/module-somerandomname/Controller/Myfile.php > patches/my_patch_name.patch`
4. `git reset HEAD vendor/vendorname/module-somerandomname/Controller/Myfile.php`
5. Do a `composer install`

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: This is the most elegant solution!

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: This should be the real solution for applying patch

Answer (score 3):

1. Add the file you want to modify::

   `git add vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php -f`
2. make changes to the original file

   `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php`
3. git diff

   `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php > yourPatchName.patch`
4. you will get the patch file (**yourPatchName.patch**) in the root directory
5. remove the changes you added to the original file manually by using ctrl+z

   `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php`
6. apply the patch using::

   `git apply yourPatchName.patch`

you will notice the changes in the original file

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simpliest way to get what you need.

Create a copy of file(f5) and change lines you need, then git diff

this is option you need  --no-index

Example:

```
 git diff --no-index  vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/PageRepository.php vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/PageRepositoryNew.php
```

will show you exactly what you need for patch.
After that change PageRepositoryNew.php to PageRepository.php in patch.

Answer (score 1):

For  creating a patch, most of the people are using Github

At git, it is easy to create a patch for a commit.
If you want to   create the patch for a commit 452 then  use `git format-patch -1 {commitId}`

**Checkout below blogs:**

https://coderwall.com/p/6aw72a/creating-patch-from-github-pull-request
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit
https://gist.github.com/emmanueltissera/19d0a8852f000cde13768dd7420a0906

For magento, you can use  below steps describe by  magento

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Magento Cloud, you can create your patch following @Ylgen method, then move the patch to the m2-hotfixes/ folder and run:

```
php vendor/bin/ece-patches apply
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Documentation:

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-patch.html#apply-a-patch-in-a-local-environment

Answer (score 1):

- Cloud is not accepting to move vendor files to git.
- So i created file in app/code folder like
  app/code/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php
- added to git then committed. Not pushed the changes to any branch.
- Then updated the modified code then executed the git diff command.
  git diff app/code/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php
- It showed the below code.
  **diff --git a/app/code/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php b/app/code/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php
  index 3ee2rd..8349152 111644
  --- a/app/code/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php
  +++ b/app/code/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php**
- I copied that above code and added in customer.patch file then removed the
  app/code/ code.
- uploaded the customer.patch file from hotfixes folder then moved to the git.
- Then remove the file from
  app/code/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/CustomerData.php
  location then commit again.

Answer (score 1):

The two answers with the most upvotes work like a charm.

In case somebody else is banging his head why it does not apply the patches, you might want to install the composer package that actually applies the patches.

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

After this composer will apply the patches

More information can be found here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html?lang=en#composer

Answer (score 0):

if you're using phpstorm you can simply right click on a file from local changes and select "Create patch from local changes"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> > **Try this code to create a custom patch**

**Step-1** Run the below command to install the patch package.

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

**Step-2** Add the below lines in your main Magento's composer.json file
[image]

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "patches-file": "composer-patches.json",
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true
}
```

**Step-3** Create patch file using this command

```
diff -u path/originalFile.php path/updateFile.php > your_patch_file_name.patch
```

I copy the original file (system.js) and paste it at the same location with a different name (systemUpdate.js). I add a new modification in a new file (systemUpdate.js). then I run the below command

```
diff -u vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/systemUpdate.js > diff.patch
```

You got diff.patch file which is your patch now updates the file path and file name. Because the file name and path must be the same. also add **a** and **b** bfore the file path.

> **Example:**  **Fix_Store_Config_Issue.patch**

```
--- a/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js   2023-01-25 22:36:53.170211591 +0530
+++ b/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js   2022-09-12 14:45:06.000000000 +0530
@@ -125,7 +125,7 @@
         let messagingLogoPosition = $('.' + location + '-messaging-logo-position').val();
         let messagingTextColor = $('.' + location + '-messaging-text-color').val();
 
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-show-value"]').val(buttonShowStatus).click();
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-layout-value"]').val(buttonLayout).click();
@@ -150,7 +150,7 @@
         let locations = ['checkout', 'productpage', 'cart'], buttonTypes = ['paypal', 'paylater', 'credit'];
         let buttonShowStatus = 1, buttonLayout = 'horizontal', buttonTagline = 0, buttonLabel = 'paypal', buttonColor = 'gold', buttonShape = 'rect', buttonSize = 'responsive';
 
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-show-value"]').val(buttonShowStatus).click();
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-layout-value"]').val(buttonLayout).click();
@@ -174,7 +174,7 @@
     window.applyButton = function () {
         let locations = ['checkout', 'productpage', 'cart'], buttonTypes = ['paypal', 'paylater', 'credit'];
 
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-show-value"]').click();
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-layout-value"]').click();
@@ -200,7 +200,7 @@
     $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-fields-payment-location-value"]').change(function () {
         hidePaypalSections();
     });
-    locations.each(function (loc) {
+    $.each(locations, function (loc) {
         $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+loc+'-fields-paypal-location-'+loc+'-button-type-value"]').change(function () {
             hidePaypalSections();
         });
@@ -215,7 +215,7 @@
         }
         merchantCountryIndex = mainLocation.attr('id').split('_')[1];
         mainType = $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+mainLocation.val()+'-fields-paypal-location-'+mainLocation.val()+'-button-type-value"]');
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             $('#row_payment_' + merchantCountryIndex + '_braintree_section_braintree_braintree_paypal_styling_button_' + loc).hide();
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('#row_payment_'+merchantCountryIndex+'_braintree_section_braintree_braintree_paypal_styling_button_'+loc+'_button_location_'+loc+'_type_' + type).hide();
```

**Step-4** Create new folder at magentoRoot -> **patches** And add your path file here. **(magentoRoot/patches/yourfile)**

**Step-5** Create a new file at the root of magento -> **composer-patches.json**

```
{
  "patches": {
    "paypal/module-braintree-core": {
      "Fix Store Configuration Tab Issue": "patches/Fix_Store_Config_Issue.patch"
    }
  }
}
```

here you can add your module packages name. In vendor path. Examples are paypal/module-braintree-core, magento/module-catalog, etc.
You can find your package name in the module's composer.json file

**Step-6** Run the below command

```
composer install 

composer update
```