# how to override the Setup/Patch/Data file in magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, setup, magento2.3.3

How to override the core "module-store/Setup/Patch/Data/DisableSid.php" into "app/code/Mymodule/Test/" module.
can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rewrite this Patch data this way.

**Patch data are run one time. So override is NOT the solution for this.**

I guess that you want to make `web/session/use_frontend_sid` field value to 1

**So, create A data patch on your custom module:** and change this field value to 1.

```
<?php


namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\MutableScopeConfigInterface;

class {ClassName} implements DataPatchInterface
{

    const SCOPE_STORE = 'store';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\MutableScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $mutableScopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        MutableScopeConfigInterface $mutableScopeConfig   
     ) {

        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->mutableScopeConfig = $mutableScopeConfig;
    }
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $this->mutableScopeConfig->setValue(self::XML_PATH_USE_FRONTEND_SID, 1, self::SCOPE_STORE);

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It's working

Answer (score 0):

@Amit Bera is right.

**The override Data Patch is not the solution. because it makes an issue on setup:upgrade command.**

The plugin and preference are not working Data patch file. So if you want to add changes to your existing core or any vendor third-party module. You need to create a custom patch.
**[Create a custom patch click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368552/82670)**

Or you can create a new patch to fix the old one by adding dependencies.

Add dependent patch file below function.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [
        \VedoreName\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data\AddPatchFileName::class,
    ];
}
```