# Multi currency site show a 0 price only in the magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, multicurrency

I installed a fresh version of magento2 with the simple data, test the payment in USD using the cash on delivery, and the payment was fine.

I added more currencies KWD, EGP, and EUR. Then configure the rates. After that, I tested the payment with EUR and it was fine. I tested the payment with EGP/KWD but the price is 0 only on the checkout page. I got that the attached image

The change of the currency works fine for all pages including orders in the admin pages.
[image: shipping page]
[image: payment page]
[image: Admin Currency Rates]
[image: Admin Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I know is late but for feature search.

Same issue here.
In my case was from Currency Symbols (vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php) method (getOutputFormat) when has to give format for price-utils.js

In case of EURO or USD the $formatted is something like this: $0.00 or €0.00 in case you have EGP the $formatted is EGP 0.00

```
$formatted = $this->formatTxt(0); 
RESULT: $0.00, €0.00, EGP 0.00

$number = $this->formatTxt(0, ['display' => \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL]); 
RESULT: 0.00, €0.00, EGP0.00
return str_replace($this->trimUnicodeDirectionMark($number), '%s', $formatted); 
RESULT: $%s, %s, EGP 0.00
```

Issue in trimUnicodeDirectionMark on

```
preg_match('/^(\x{200E}|\x{200F})/u', $string, $match)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, Many times this issue is a big problem. I found below file is responsible for this issue.

```
vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php
```

Solution: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/33966/commits/82c1a4d1137f747b9551e7d4d87106bf2c726b9e

You need to update your core Currency.php file. You can not overwrite this core file in your custom module. I tried but it's not working. So I created a custom patch for it.

created custom patch click here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368552/82670

> **Latest Magento version [2.4.6.p2] Custom Patch for fix this issue**

```
--- a/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php    2023-09-20 10:44:14.635173580 +0200
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php    2023-09-20 10:41:29.819340923 +0200
@@ -14,6 +14,7 @@
 use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface as LocalResolverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\NumberFormatterFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
+use Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter;
 
 /**
  * Currency model
@@ -85,7 +86,7 @@
     private $numberFormatterFactory;
 
     /**
-     * @var \Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter
+     * @var NumberFormatter
      */
     private $numberFormatter;
 
@@ -444,9 +445,9 @@
      * Get NumberFormatter object from cache.
      *
      * @param array $options
-     * @return \Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter
+     * @return NumberFormatter
      */
-    private function getNumberFormatter(array $options): \Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter
+    private function getNumberFormatter(array $options): NumberFormatter
     {
         $locale = $this->localeResolver->getLocale() . ($this->getCode() ? '@currency=' . $this->getCode() : '');
         $key = 'currency_' . hash('sha256', $locale . $this->serializer->serialize($options));
@@ -479,6 +480,7 @@
         if (array_key_exists(LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_DISPLAY, $options)
             && $options[LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_DISPLAY] === \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL) {
             $this->numberFormatter->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '');
+            $this->numberFormatter->setPattern(str_replace('¤', '', $this->numberFormatter->getPattern()));
         }
         if (array_key_exists('precision', $options)) {
             $this->numberFormatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, $options['precision']);
@@ -503,7 +505,7 @@
     public function getOutputFormat()
     {
         $formatted = $this->formatTxt(0);
-        $number = $this->formatTxt(0, ['display' => \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL]);
+        $number = str_replace($this->getCurrencySymbol(), '', $formatted);
         return $formatted !== null ? str_replace($this->trimUnicodeDirectionMark($number), '%s', $formatted) : '';
     }
 
@@ -581,9 +583,9 @@
      * This method removes LRM and RLM marks from string
      *
      * @param string $string
-     * @return $this
+     * @return string
      */
-    private function trimUnicodeDirectionMark($string)
+    private function trimUnicodeDirectionMark(string $string): string
     {
         if (preg_match('/^(\x{200E}|\x{200F})/u', $string, $match)) {
             $string = preg_replace('/^' . $match[1] . '/u', '', $string);
```