# Uncaught TypeError: locations.each is not a function in Magento admin showing occasionally on system configuration page in 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

While accessing a Magento admin system configuration page, facing the below error that prevents the save config button.

```
Uncaught TypeError: locations.each is not a function
```

When clicking on `system.js`, seems to be loading from the PayPal_Braintree module.

```
locations.each(function (loc) {
        $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+loc+'-fields-paypal-location-'+loc+'-button-type-value"]').change(function () {
            hidePaypalSections();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step-1** Run the below command to install the patch package.

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

**Step-2** add the below lines in your composer.json file
[image]

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "patches-file": "composer-patches.json",
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true
}
```

**Step-3** Create new file at root od magento -> **composer-patches.json**

```
{
  "patches": {
    "paypal/module-braintree-core": {
      "Fix Store Configuration Tab Issue": "patches/Fix_Store_Config_Issue.patch"
    }
  }
}
```

**Step-4** Create new folder at magentoRoot -> **patches**

**Step-5** Create new file at magentoRoot/patches -> **Fix_Store_Config_Issue.patch**

```
--- a/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js   2023-01-25 22:36:53.170211591 +0530
+++ b/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js   2022-09-12 14:45:06.000000000 +0530
@@ -125,7 +125,7 @@
         let messagingLogoPosition = $('.' + location + '-messaging-logo-position').val();
         let messagingTextColor = $('.' + location + '-messaging-text-color').val();
 
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-show-value"]').val(buttonShowStatus).click();
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-layout-value"]').val(buttonLayout).click();
@@ -150,7 +150,7 @@
         let locations = ['checkout', 'productpage', 'cart'], buttonTypes = ['paypal', 'paylater', 'credit'];
         let buttonShowStatus = 1, buttonLayout = 'horizontal', buttonTagline = 0, buttonLabel = 'paypal', buttonColor = 'gold', buttonShape = 'rect', buttonSize = 'responsive';
 
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-show-value"]').val(buttonShowStatus).click();
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-layout-value"]').val(buttonLayout).click();
@@ -174,7 +174,7 @@
     window.applyButton = function () {
         let locations = ['checkout', 'productpage', 'cart'], buttonTypes = ['paypal', 'paylater', 'credit'];
 
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-show-value"]').click();
                 $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-layout-value"]').click();
@@ -200,7 +200,7 @@
     $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-fields-payment-location-value"]').change(function () {
         hidePaypalSections();
     });
-    locations.each(function (loc) {
+    $.each(locations, function (loc) {
         $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+loc+'-fields-paypal-location-'+loc+'-button-type-value"]').change(function () {
             hidePaypalSections();
         });
@@ -215,7 +215,7 @@
         }
         merchantCountryIndex = mainLocation.attr('id').split('_')[1];
         mainType = $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+mainLocation.val()+'-fields-paypal-location-'+mainLocation.val()+'-button-type-value"]');
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             $('#row_payment_' + merchantCountryIndex + '_braintree_section_braintree_braintree_paypal_styling_button_' + loc).hide();
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('#row_payment_'+merchantCountryIndex+'_braintree_section_braintree_braintree_paypal_styling_button_'+loc+'_button_location_'+loc+'_type_' + type).hide();
```

**Step-6** Run the below command

```
composer install 

composer update
```

**Note: Above Patch file: Fix_Store_Config_Issue.patch is only work on Magento 2.4.5, for the other version you need to create your own patch file.**

**Create Custom Patch** : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368552/82670

Comment: Where is the source of this patch?

Comment: do you by chance have the source files after the patch? vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js when I patch I got error error: corrupt patch at line 47

Comment: I used Magento version 2.4.5-p1. Please check file link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mZG6I7SXx5x4MMRCg84OulmcdUh7mK70/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so this change is already in 2.4.5-p1? I was using that version and still getting this error sometimes in the adin area. I have just disabled the paypal braintree module for now since we don't use it anywyas.

Comment: No, I send you an updated file after the patch apply. Which Magento version you are using? For more, you can connect me on skype.

Comment: thanks @Msquare now I understood

Comment: I appreciate your help. I've solved this problem（only for magento 2.4.6）. I've put the method below. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370147/magento-2-4-6-uncaught-typeerror-locations-each-is-not-system-js195-a-function

Answer (score 3):

Use the patch to get it fixed.

```
diff --git a/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js
b/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js
index 1313f215e..cfa34c760 100644
--- a/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js
+++ b/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js
@@ -200,7 +200,7 @@ require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert', 'mage/translate', 'domReady!'],
     $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-fields-payment-location-value"]').change(function () {
         hidePaypalSections();
     });
-    locations.each(function (loc) {
+    $.each(locations, function (loc) {
         $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+loc+'-fields-paypal-location-'+loc+'-button-type-value"]').change(function () {
             hidePaypalSections();
         });
@@ -215,7 +215,7 @@ require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert', 'mage/translate', 'domReady!'],
         }
         merchantCountryIndex = mainLocation.attr('id').split('_')[1];
         mainType = $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+mainLocation.val()+'-fields-paypal-location-'+mainLocation.val()+'-button-type-value"]');
-        locations.each(function (loc) {
+        $.each(locations, function (loc) {
             $('#row_payment_' + merchantCountryIndex + '_braintree_section_braintree_braintree_paypal_styling_button_' + loc).hide();
             buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
                 $('#row_payment_'+merchantCountryIndex+'_braintree_section_braintree_braintree_paypal_styling_button_'+loc+'_button_location_'+loc+'_type_' + type).hide();
```