# Magento 2.4.6 Uncaught TypeError: locations.each is not system.js:195 a function

Tags: admin, admin-panel, magento2.4.6

I use Magento2.4.6. When I upgraded to the latest version of the Mage fan Blog, after I entered the background Configuration, I could not save or open any other menus.

```
   Uncaught TypeError: locations.each is not a function
    at system.js:195:15
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1696:33)
    at Module.check (require.js:883:51)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1139:34)
    at require.js:134:23
    at require.js:1189:21
    at each (require.js:59:31)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1188:17)
    at Module.check (require.js:938:30)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1176:22)
```

**https://prnt.sc/a6NwOndAK5q_**

I tried this method, but it still didn't solve the problem.

**[Uncaught TypeError: locations.each is not a function in Magento admin showing occasionally on system configuration page in 2.4.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359368/uncaught-typeerror-locations-each-is-not-a-function-in-magento-admin-showing-oc)**

**https://prnt.sc/gYxCrLnMFLn6**

How to solved this problem.

Comment: Could you kindly provide the system.xml file?

Comment: yes, the patch is not working because you used a different version of magento.  the patch is for magento 2.4.5.  Which magento version are using? I will provide you with a patch based on your magento version.

Comment: You can create custom patch using this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256571/how-to-create-a-magento-2-patch/368552#368552

Comment: I appreciate your help. I've solved this problem. I've put the method below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you already know there is a Patch for this issue and it work but if you want to directly apply patch then it not works because there always few changes in JS file based on versions

So you have to find the JS file `vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js`

After that find `locations. Each(` and replace it with `$.each(locations,` and also review if there is need of closing round bracket or not

If it works then create a patch for yourself and use composer as you are doing right now

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help. I may try it later, as it seems more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by directly modifying the system.js file.

add the below lines in your vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/adminhtml/web/js/system.js file

```
 locations.each(function (loc) {
    $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+loc+'-fields-paypal-location-'+loc+'-button-type-value"]').change(function () {
        hidePaypalSections();
    });
});
```

to

```
 locations.each(function (loc) {
    buttonTypes.each(function (type) {
             $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-show-value"]').val(buttonShowStatus).click();
             $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-' + loc + '-groups-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-fields-button-location-' + loc + '-type-' + type + '-layout-value"]').val(buttonLayout).click();
    $('[data-ui-id="select-groups-braintree-section-groups-braintree-groups-braintree-paypal-groups-styling-groups-button-'+loc+'-fields-paypal-location-'+loc+'-button-type-value"]').change(function () {
        hidePaypalSections();
    });
});
```

[image]