# Magento 2.4.5 In Customer Forgot password link, reset my password button is disabled after the upgrade

Tags: customer-account, magento2.4.5, forgot-password

[image]After the upgrade from 2.4.3 to 2.4.5, I see that new code has been added in the upgraded forgotpassword.html that is disabling the reset button.  How can I enable it please

Edit:  Extending forgotpassword.html in custom module and removing the disabling code for Reset Password button works.  Looking for an optimal solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature introduced in Magento 2.4.5, but **looks like** it does not works as expected.

Since Magento 2.4.5, to support Google Recaptcha in the forgot password page, Magento add `disabled` HTML attribute to the forgot password button **in case** you use Google reCaptcha (enabled) and already configured the Google API Key for the reCaptcha.
In theory, if the attribute `disabled` HTML attribute is added to the forgot password button, once the customer filled out all required information, the button should be show. But **looks like** it does not works as expected. If you entered your email and passed reCaptcha but the button still disabled, I think it is bug from Magento code base.

There are some solutions to resolve this issue **at this time**, you can choose **one** that fit your need:

1. Apply a patch file to remove `disabled` HTML attribute in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/forgotpassword.phtml`.

Here you replace:

```
<button type="submit" class="action submit primary" id="send2" <?php if ($forgotPasswordButtonViewModel->disabled()): ?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif; ?>><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reset My Password')) ?></span></button>
```

with

```
<button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reset My Password')) ?></span></button>
```

2. Disable `recaptcha_disable_forgot_password_button` plugin file to remove `disabled` HTML attribute in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/forgotpassword.phtml`.
3. Override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/forgotpassword.phtml` file in your theme or your module to remove `disabled` HTML attribute in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/forgotpassword.phtml`.

Here you replace:

```
<button type="submit" class="action submit primary" id="send2" <?php if ($forgotPasswordButtonViewModel->disabled()): ?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif; ?>><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reset My Password')) ?></span></button>
```

with

```
<button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reset My Password')) ?></span></button>
```

4. Investigate the JS issue and fix it by yourself: investigate why after you filled out all required fields and pass reCaptcha, code does not fire in `dataForm.on('invalid-form.validate'` function which located in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/block-submit-on-send.js` and fix the issue.

Related documents:

- How to create patch: [Create magento 2 Patch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256571/create-magento-2-patch/315195#315195)
- How to disable a plugin: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/#disabling-plugins

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply...I have already implemented No.3 as a temporary fix.  I will update you after I investigate on other solutions.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Siri That sound great!

Comment: Accepting the answer as disabling the plugin works and seems to be the better option as of now.

Comment: @TuVan I Am facing the same issue with the Login and Create account button in Magento Commerce Cloud 2.4.6-p3. Is there any patch for this issue?

Comment: @VigneshBala you can create a patch based on my instructions and the instructions I shared above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to extend the form\forgotpassword.phtml
and add the following codes to add the reset button,

```
           <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reset My Password')) ?></span></button>
```

> 

```
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Customer/js/block-submit-on-send": {
            "formId": "form-validate"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have extended already as a temporary fix, am looking for optimal solution..thank you