# Composer Patch for Third-Party module fixes

Tags: magento2, composer, patches

I'm running into a scenario where I need to create a new model to fix some issues with a third-party package and modify a few files. I have created a composer patch to modify the files but not sure, how to create a new file with the composer patch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here The Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a composer patch for an extension you can create with the reference given below

Composer Patch creation [Click Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256580/90013)