# Magento 2 - after Plugin for \Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy not working

Tags: magento2, plugin, csp

Why is my plugin not getting called?

**app/code/Company/Configurator/etc/module.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Configurator" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Csp"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/Configurator/etc/di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy">
        <plugin name="company_configurator_after_fetch_policy"
                type="Company\Configurator\Plugin\FetchPolicyPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/Configurator/Plugin/FetchPolicyPlugin.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Configurator\Plugin;

class FetchPolicyPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy $subject
     * @param string[] $result
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function afterGetHostSources(\Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy $subject, array $result): array
    {
        // Modify the $result array here, if needed
        // For example, add an additional host source
        $result[] = 'example.com';  // I have set a xdebug breakpoint here, but it is never hit.

        return $result;
    }
}
```

The original method is getting called, but not my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet, you're trying to plugin to the method `getHostSources` of the `Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy` class.

However, this method is called within the merge method of the `Magento\Csp\Model\Collector\FetchPolicyMerger` class and is directly passed as an argument to the array_merge function.

In Magento, when methods are called this way, plugins (interceptors) might not be triggered because of how PHP resolves function arguments. This is a known limitation in the Magento 2 plugin system.

This means that the method `getHostSources` is being called and its results are used directly as arguments for the `array_merge` function. PHP will resolve these arguments before making the call to `array_merge`.

As a result, the plugin is not getting triggered because from a PHP perspective, it's not a direct method call, but rather the method's result is being used as a function argument.

A workaround to this problem would be to extend the `Magento\Csp\Model\Collector\FetchPolicyMerger` class and override the respective methods. Alternatively, if it fits your use case, you might consider creating a plugin for the merge method.

Answer (score 1):

The `Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy` class is instantiated using the `new` keyword and not by dependency injection.

```
new FetchPolicy()
```

Therefore, using a plugin or preference will not work.

To apply the change to this class, I suggest creating a custom composer patch and applying it via composer.

For instructions on how to create a custom composer patch, please refer to this topic: [How to create a Magento 2 Patch?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256571/create-magento-2-patch)

For instructions on how to apply composer patches, please refer to this document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html?lang=en#composer

Comment: But what if I upgrade my magento 2 and it conflicts with my patch?

Comment: Then you need to update the patch file content again :). This is the only preferred way to modify the `Magento\Csp\Model\Policy\FetchPolicy` class. However, don't worry about the magento upgrade, this class rarely gets the update, the last update was 3 years ago (Magento 2.4.2). You can check the git commits history at https://github.com/magento/magento2/commits/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Csp/Model/Policy/FetchPolicy.php