# Magento2.4.6 issue: During inheritance of JsonSerializable

Tags: php, magento2.4.6, issue

I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command in magento2.4.6.

But I got error like this.

[image]

Ced\PwaNotifications\Ui\Component\Listing\Massaction\Templates.php

```
<?php

namespace Ced\PwaNotifications\Ui\Component\Listing\MassAction;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable;
use \Ced\PwaNotifications\Model\ResourceModel\Template\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class Options
 */
class Templates implements JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Additional options params
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $data;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * Base URL for subactions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $urlPath;

    /**
     * Param name for subactions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $paramName;

    /**
     * Additional params for subactions
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $additionalData = [];

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Get action options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function jsonSerialize():mixed
    {
        $i = 0;
        if ($this->options === null) {
            // get the massaction data from the database table
            $templateCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

            if (!count($templateCollection)) {
                return $this->options;
            }
            //make a array of massaction
            foreach ($templateCollection as $key => $value) {
                $options[$i]['value'] = $value->getId();
                $options[$i]['label'] = $value->getTitle();
                $i++;
            }
            $this->prepareData();
            foreach ($options as $optionCode) {
                $this->options[$optionCode['value']] = [
                    'type' => $optionCode['value'],
                    'label' => $optionCode['label'],
                ];

                if ($this->urlPath && $this->paramName) {
                    $this->options[$optionCode['value']]['url'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        $this->urlPath,
                        [$this->paramName => $optionCode['value']]
                    );
                }

                $this->options[$optionCode['value']] = array_merge_recursive(
                    $this->options[$optionCode['value']],
                    $this->additionalData
                );
            }

            // return the massaction data
            $this->options = array_values($this->options);
        }
        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare addition data for subactions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareData()
    {

        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'urlPath':
                    $this->urlPath = $value;
                    break;
                case 'paramName':
                    $this->paramName = $value;
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->additionalData[$key] = $value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the `Ced\PwaNotifications\Ui\Component\Listing\Massaction\Templates::jsonSerialize()` method in your third-party module (Ced_PwaNotifications) has a different the return type compared to its parent's method, `JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize`.

To resolve this issue, you can try upgrading the Ced_PwaNotifications module to the latest version, remove the **generated** directory, and recompile code (`bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

If the issue persists, you'll need to override `Ced\PwaNotifications\Ui\Component\Listing\Massaction\Templates::jsonSerialize()` method or create a custom composer patch in order to change it's return type.

The code for that method should similar to this:

```
public function jsonSerialize(): mixed
{
...
}
```

Read more about how to apply composer patches here https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html?lang=en#composer

You can take a look at this page to know how to create a custom
composer patch: [How to create a Magento 2 Patch?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256571/create-magento-2-patch)

Comment: How to upgrading the Ced_PwaNotifications module to the latest version?

Comment: Since you installed that module manually in `app/code`, follow these steps to upgrade that module to the latest version: 1. Download the latest version of the module from **the module provider website**. 2. Remove **all files and directories** in the `Ced_PwaNotifications` module located at app/code/Ced/PwaNotifications. 3. Extract the latest version of the module to the `Ced_PwaNotifications` module located at app/code/Ced/PwaNotifications. 4. Run the upgrade command and recompile code (and redeploy static content if you are not in the **Developer** mode). You're done!